# Check the following hypothesis: $H_{0}: m_{1} = m_{2}$ against the alternative $H_{1}: m_{1} \ne m_{2}$

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, random-variable

I am new in statistics and I have to solve a problem involving hypothesis testing (first of this kind for me). Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

The statement:

From two piles of pieces, each of them made by a different machine, has been extracted a selection of $n_{1} = 10$ pieces from the first and $n_{2} = 12$ pieces from the second. We notice the following results regarding diameter of pieces in each selection:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|} 
x_{i} & 3.4 & 3.5 & 3.7 & 3.9 \\ \hline
n_{1i} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
x_{i} & 3.2 & 3.4 & 3.6 \\ \hline
n_{2i} & 2 & 2 & 8 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Where $x_{i}$ its the diameter of the piece, $n_{1i}$ it's the number of pieces from the first pile and $n_{2i}$ from the second pile.
Knowing that the diameter of the made pieces it's a normal random distributed variable, check the following hypothesis: $H_{0}: m_{1} = m_{2}$ against the alternative $H_{1}: m_{1} \ne m_{2}$

Comment: You might get better responses if you follow the guidance in the [tag:self-study] https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-study

Answer (score 0):

Comparing means of normally distributed samples is the classical job of Student's t-test. In R that would be:

```
one <- c(3.4, 3.4, 3.5,3.5,3.5, 3.7,3.7,3.7,3.7, 3.9)
two <- c(3.2,3.2, 3.4,3.4, 3.6,3.6,3.6,3.6,3.6,3.6,3.6,3.6)
t.test(one, two, var.equal = TRUE)
```

with the result

```
    Two Sample t-test

data:  one and two
t = 1.4484, df = 20, p-value = 0.163
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.04401711  0.24401711
sample estimates:
 mean of x mean of y 
      3.6       3.5
```

This leads to the quite difficult to interpret p-value. Because that is larger then 0.05, one would usually not determine, that there is a difference.

If this was not for teaching but for real life problems, I'd consider an easier to read approach called BEST, which you can find here: http://www.sumsar.net/best_online/
but that is not what is taught to a beginner´.

Comment: Wary of a t-test because the second sample is so far from normal, I tried a permutation test [See Sec 4](http://ww2.amstat.org/publications/jse/v18n1/eudey.pdf), using the pooled t statistic as metric, but it does not lead to rejection. A Wilcoxon signed-rank test is inappropriate because of the ties.